# mysql query LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-like

I need to select any occurrence of a word (keyword search) on two tables and the query I made is like this:

```
SELECT t1.fname, t1.lname, t2.* FROM t1 , t2  
     WHERE t2.title LIKE "%test%" 
     OR t2.desc LIKE "%test%" 
     OR t2.inc LIKE "%test%" 
     OR t1.fname LIKE "%test%" 
     OR t1.lname LIKE "%test%" 
     AND t1.c_id = t2.c_id;
```

As there is a lot of data in database, this particular search (with 'test' keyword) takes several minutes and I'm wondering how to optimize this.
I tried with LEFT JOIN but it seems I did it wrong - as the results defers pretty much, but it the query is executed very quickly.

It is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t2 AS a 
  LEFT JOIN t1 AS b ON a.c_id = b.c_id 
    WHERE a.desc LIKE '%test%' 
     OR a.title LIKE '%test%' 
     OR a.inc LIKE '%test%' 
     OR b.fname LIKE '%test%'  
     OR b.lname LIKE '%test%';
```

Any help would be much appreciated ... thanks.

Comment: Whach database engine you are using?

Comment: MyIsam ... tables were built before, I'm fixing bugs

Comment: If you have MyISAM tables then you can use MATCH..AGAINST keywords to search a string in multiple columns. Check my answer it will give you the idea of how to use MATCH..AGAINST in query

Comment: yes, I wanted to ... but not all of them are MyISAM :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first statement is not what you intended: the`AND` clause takes [precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//operator-precedence.html) over `OR` so you have actually written

```
t2.title LIKE "%test%" 
OR t2.desc LIKE "%test%" 
OR t2.inc LIKE "%test%" 
OR t1.fname LIKE "%test%" 
OR (t1.lname LIKE "%test%" AND t1.c_id = t2.c_id;)
```

This finally results in a *(somewhat skewed)* [natural join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join) between t1 and t2 returning far to many rows.

Comment: yes, must have been right - the results are not ok. I tried what you suggested, but it is the same. I assume, Left join would be better?

Comment: @Angel M - I haven't suggested anything, merely showed you the error in your original statement. I don't know your use case but I think you should replace the `LEFT JOIN` with an `FULL OUTER JOIN` to get results from either t1 or t2.

Comment: I meant - showing me the error - and I found a way - and now I had the right results.

Answer (score 2):

Try **MATCH..AGAINST** to search multiple columns for **MyISAM** tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t2 AS a 
INNER JOIN t1 AS b ON a.c_id = b.c_id 
WHERE MATCH (a.desc, a.title, a.inc, b.fname, b.lname) AGAINST ('test')
```

Check this link [**MYSQL FULL TEXT SEARCH**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)